# iWork and iLife are not free after reinstall

Tags: macbook-pro, mac-appstore, apple-id, install, iwork

I recently bought a Macbook Pro 13" Early-2015 from a guy who used it only once and then reinstalled it for selling (already upgraded to the latest El-Capitan).
After I set up my Apple ID I couldn't download the iLife & iWork apps for free, they all cost money..
I have them all free on my iPhone though.

What are the necessary steps to be able to download them for free? I know it should be on every Mac after 2013. The one I bought is 2015.

The Macbook was purchased in an official Apple Store in the United States, I have the receipt.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you already register the "new" mac with your same apple id. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the [iWork '09](http://www.chip.de/downloads/Apple-iWork-09_34450001.html?icp=sigExpired) and [iLife '11](https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=QaAY&id=0BxBv4YtS92XIblh1a0x4alYtZU0) trials and install them. The AppStore will then offer to upgrade these old apps to the current version. See [these](http://maypalo.com/2013/10/25/how-to-download-iwork-ilife-apps-for-free-on-mac-leaked-links/) [or these instructions](http://www.cultofmac.com/306118/download-apples-iwork-apps-older-macs-free/).